# definition of connectedness by means of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Is there any way to define the connectedness in metric spaces using sequences?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit artifical (and uses sequential openness, essentially), but I think this holds:

$(X,d)$ is connected whenever we write $A_1 \cup A_2 = X$, then there is a convergent sequence $x_n \to x$ that is not eventually in $A_1$ or $A_2$.

Comment: This comes from the 5th equivalence on this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space), right? (about separated sets)

Comment: Or 1 from disjoint open sets.